# is there short proof of uniqueness of solutions of a linear two-dimensional non-autonomous system of ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for short and simple (accessible for an economist with calculus background) proof of uniqueness of solutions of a linear two-dimensional non-autonomous system of ODE.

Comment: How good is the economist with the Grönwall lemma? Its terms for a start and, more advanced, some of the proof? This is the shortest variant for the uniqueness proof. The other variant takes the full proof of the existence theorem and extracts the uniqueness from the uniqueness of the Banach fixed-point theorem used therein.

Comment: Not too happy with Cauchy theorem of existence and uniqueness.  We are jointly working on economic problem (I do the math part) and he insists on understanding the proof of uniqueness of solutions of the linear system we are working on.  I cite the Cauchy theorem, then prove that our system satisfies the conditions of the theorem.  I guess the path can not be straighter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a linear system $y'(t)=A(t)y(t)+b(t)$, the difference $u$ of two solutions $x,y$ is itself the solution of the homogeneous system
$$
u'(t)=y'(t)-x'(t)=A(t)(y(t)-x(t))=A(t)u(t).
$$
Now apply vector and associated matrix norms
$$
\|u'(t)\|\le \|A(t)\|\,\|u(t)\|
$$
By the Grönwall lemma, this results in the upper bound
$$
\|u(t)\|\le \exp\left(\int_{t_0}^t\|A(s)\|\,ds\right)\|u(t_0)\|.
$$
So when the two solutions are equal at $t_0$, they also have to be equal for any $t>t_0$. A similar argument goes also for $t<t_0$.

---

To get that bound, first consider the exact equation $d'(t)=\|A(t)\|d(t)$ which has the solution $d(t)=e^{c(t)}d(t_0)$ with $c'(t)=\|A(t)\|$, $c(t_0)=0$. Now consider the difference $h_a(t)=\|u(t)\|-(\|u(t_0)\|+a)e^{c(s)}$ for some $a>0$ under the integral identities and inequalities
\begin{align}
\|u(t)\|&=\|u(t_0)\|+\left\|\int_{t_0}^tu'(s)\,ds\right\|
\le\|u(t_0)\|+\int_{t_0}^t\left\|u'(s)\right\|\,ds
\\
&\le \|u(t_0)\|+\int_{t_0}^t\|A(s)\|\,\|u(s)\|\,ds
\\
\\
e^{c(t)}&=1+\int_{t_0}^te^{c(s)}c'(s)\,ds
\\[1em]\hline
h_a(t)=\|u(t)\|-(\|u(t_0)\|+a)e^{c(t)}&
\le-a+\int_{t_0}^t\|A(s)\|\,\Bigl(\|u(s)\|-(\|u(t_0)\|+a)e^{c(s)}\Bigr)\,ds
\\&=-a+\int_{t_0}^t\|A(s)\|\,h_a(s)\,ds.
\end{align}
From this one concludes that there can be no $t$ where the $h_a(t)\ge 0$,, as then there would be a minimal such $t$ with $h_a(t)=0$ and from the last inequality $h_a(t)\le-a<0$ would follow in contradiction.

Now as
$$
\|u(t)\|<(\|u(t_0)\|+a)e^{c(t)}
$$
for all $a>0$, it follows that in the limit 
$$
\|u(t)\|\le\|u(t_0)\|e^{c(t)}.
$$

Comment: could you give a textbook citation for this?

Comment: how do you define a matrix norm?

Comment: You can take the max norm for the vectors, then the associated matrix norm is the row-sum norm. This should be simple enough.

Comment: May I ask how to apply Gr\"onwall lemma to the normed inequality?  In the sources that I saw  the lemma is provided for one-dimensional real-valued case.

Comment: Consider the function $d(t)=\|u(t)\|$, then $|d'(t)|\le \|u'(t)\|$ so that the inequality of the vector case reduces to the scalar case.

Comment: how do you derive $|d'(t)|\leq\|u'(t)\|$? I see non-differentiability of a norm as a problem. Am I missing the point?

Comment: In principle yes, but you can work around this by going one integration order higher. The result in the end is the same. Or first transform $$\|u(t)\|\le\|u(t_0)\|+\int_{t_0}^t\|A(s)\|\,\|u(s)\|\,ds$$ so that there are no derivatives in the formula.

Comment: in my case, I derived $\|u'(t)\| \leq \|A(t)\| \|u(t)\|$. Now I need to apply the Gronwall's inequality in 2-dimensions which I can't find anywhere.  By "one integration order higher" you mean the Gronwall's integral inequality?

Comment: If matrix $A$ is constant, can I go without Gronwall's lemma?  If I write out $u(t)$ as matrix exponential, and bound its norm in a usual way, I think I get there.

Comment: Yes, that is the easy case. I have added the proof with the general proof strategy, solve the exact equation to get some solution $d$, prove that $d(t)+a\,e(s)$ is an upper bound for all $a>0$, and some convenient positive function $e$, take the limit $a\to 0$.

Comment: interesting... so you introduce $d$ as a solution of the exact equation and then it happens to be $\|u\|$…?

Comment: and then you reduce the vector case to 1 dimensional case...wow